# Can i change the locale oon MySQL Source-Configuration Options

Tags: mysql, locale, my.cnf

I've been working on MySQL recently, and I'm changing the default settings to my convenience. I change the locale from 'en_US' to 'es_PA' because this is where I live, and I want to check the time format that way.

The thing is that normally, every time I turn on my Rpi and enter the MySQL server, the locale is at 'en_US'. so I enter the super user and do this:

```
set global lc_time_names = 'es_PA';
```

So that changes everyone's locale. But whenever I disconnect from the server, and turn off the Rpi, the locale changes back to 'en_US'.

So, my questions are two:

1. Am I changing the locale right?
2. Is there a way i can change it by default on the my.cnf like I did with the UTF8 (character-set)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify all long options to MySQL as a `.my.cnf` setting. There is an `--init-command` option, which you can use to always execute when connecting. So, if you set the variable in that command, you're good to go.

Something like this should work:

```
[mysql]
init_command="SET lc_time_names='es_PA';"
```